# Filter a list of dict with values that include a specific list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I've a list of items like:

```
items_list = [
    {'attributes': ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['bar', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['foo', 'foobar']},
]
```

I'm looking at an optimized way of filtering it based on another list (which can have any length).

For example `attributes = ['bar', 'foobar']` should return the first two values.

The current working solution is:

```
def yield_items(items_list, attributes):
    for item in items_list:
        if attributes.issubset(item['attributes']):
            yield item
```

But doing it for thousands of values takes a lot of time, it iterates the full list of items at every step. I'd have used a dict if it wasn't a "subset of" but not sure how to do it right in this situation.

Comment: yes @yolomep, correted.

Comment: sorry, what are you trying to do? can you give more examples?

Comment: @Beki i'm looking at reducing the complexity of this function. O(n2) to O(n) seems achievable with some kind of indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have improved the performance time slightly, this was achieved by

- Pre transforming attributes all at once
- Calculating the equality of each element of attributes to each element of items_list without the use of loops. (This was achieved by making sure the dimensions of attributes were broadcastable with np.expand_dims)
- Using `itertools compress` to filter `items_list` at `True` values in `indexes`, rather than calculating the index locations and using list comprehension to slice `items_list`

```
items_list = [
    {'attributes': ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['foo', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['bar', 'foobar']}
]*10000
start = timer()
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
matrix = mlb.fit_transform([item["attributes"] for item in items_list])
attributes = np.expand_dims(mlb.transform([["bar", "foobar"]]*2000), 1)
indexes = np.all(np.equal(matrix, attributes), axis=2)
for i in indexes:
    filtered_list_3 = list(compress(items_list, i))
print(f' > {timer() - start}s')
```

The timings on my PC were:

```
 My First Method: 15.832297399999788s
 Jibsgrls improved method:  5.54648300000008s
 My second method: 1.8749351999999817s
```

**Original Answer**

Using the `filter` method and sets allows this code to run relatively fast.

```
items_list = [
    {'attributes': ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['bar', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['foo', 'foobar']},
]*10000
attributes = set(['bar', 'foobar'])
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: attributes.issubset(set(x["attributes"])), items_list))
```

The slowest part of this code is printing the item, replacing `print(item)` with `pass` makes this code run almost instantly for a list of 30000 dictionaries

Comment: However if you wanted to check something like `['boo', 'boo', 'boo']` this code would not work

Comment: `filter` returns an iterator, so if you call list(filtered_list) it'll take a lot of time.

Comment: try: 
items_list = [
    {'attributes': [1, 2, 3]},
    {'attributes': [2, 3]},
    {'attributes': [1, 3]},
]*10000

for attributes in [set([1, 3]) for _ in range(20000)]:
    filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: attributes.issubset(set(x["attributes"])), items_list))

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, doing list(filtered_list) in my code takes milliseconds. Unless I have misunderstood what you need it to do

Comment: yes it's only for one value, try: `for attributes in [set([1, 3]) for _ in range(20000)]: filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: attributes.issubset(set(x["attributes"])), items_list))`

Comment: @Jibsgrl True, Ill have another go later on

Answer (score 0):

So i found some kind of solution, using sklearn and numpy. it's fast but I'm not 100% convinced. I'm sharing it if someone has a better idea:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from timeit import default_timer as timer

items_list = [
    {'attributes': ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['foo', 'foobar']},
    {'attributes': ['bar', 'foobar']},
]*10000


# Answer proposition from @Tom McLean
start = timer()
for attributes in [set(['bar', 'foobar']) for _ in range(2000)]:
    filtered_list_1 = list(filter(lambda x: attributes.issubset(set(x["attributes"])), items_list))

print(f' > {timer() - start}s')
# > 12.661514799998258s

# New Proposition
start = timer()
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
matrix = mlb.fit_transform([item['attributes'] for item in items_list])

for attributes in [set(['bar', 'foobar']) for _ in range(2000)]:
    vector = mlb.transform([list(attributes)])
    result = np.where(np.dot(matrix, np.transpose(vector)) >= np.sum(vector))
    filtered_list_2 = [items_list[i] for i in list(result[0])]

print(f' > {timer() - start}s')
# > 4.712411800006521s
```

So the last one is 4s instead of 12.

Comment: I managed to improve the running time, I've updated my answer if you want to have a look